# Visual Studio and libgit2 Git Commit Error In Different Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, bitbucket

While commiting from Visual Studio got my GIT repo, I get the following error below.  It's weird because I have another copy of the project that uses the same repository and that solution commits just fine, same repo and everything. Clues?

```
An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
This transport isn't implemented. Sorry
```

Also if I go to the folder and do it via another GIT Guid or command prompt it works fine on that same folder.

Comment: Are you trying to commit files that reside on a network share? LibGit2 doesn't support that, but the commandline does. It's a limitation of the library that Visual Studio uses to communicate to Git.

Comment: Can you post the relevant `.git/config`s from the two repositories?  I suspect that one remote is configured with `ssh` (which is not supported) and the other is configured with `http` (which is).

Comment: That was it, both configs were different not sure how that happened.  Ed if you post that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: I got the same error, but this one was from a fresh repo off of their cloud service.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Unfortunately, Visual Studio Tools for Git do not yet support remote repositories using the SSH protocol, only HTTP and HTTPS.

Investigate the `.git/config` in each repository to ensure that you did not clone one repository with SSH.  If you did, try to switch the remote to an HTTPS endpoint.

Comment: Yup.  This.  I had a space in front of the https inside of the double quotes that vs wrapped my path in, and it caused the vs parser to not pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by doing a pull from Team Explorer in VS 2013 without having any solution open. Just do this one time.

This worked, and since then I haven't seen libgit error for any other solution as well.

This is tested for VS 2012 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I was running VS2012 Pro on Windows 7 and got this error. Checked all of the above but the config files were the same. Had pending windows updates and a reboot cured it.